# How to convert Ninject "Filter \ Attribute"-Binding to Autofac?

Tags: ninject, autofac, actionfilterattribute

I have MVC and WebAPI filterattributes with parameters that should rise some actionfilters. We're switching to autofac now and I need to convert the DI-Definition.

In Ninject I have something like this:

```
Kernel.BindFilter<ShopAuthorizationMVCFilter>(System.Web.Mvc.FilterScope.Controller, 0)
    .WhenControllerHas<ShopAuthorizationMVC>()
    .InRequestScope()
    .WithConstructorArgumentFromControllerAttribute<ShopAuthorizationMVC>("rechte", o => o.Rechte);
```

I can decorate Actions and controllers like this:

```
[ShopAuthorizationMVC(RightsEnum.CanAccessMycontroller)]
public class MyController : Controller {}
```

This works fine with Ninject, but I have absolutely no Idea how to write this in Auotofac.

What I've got so far is:

```
builder.Register(c => 
    new ShopAuthorizationMVCFilter(c.Resolve<IAuthClass>(), default(RightsEnum[])))
    .AsActionFilterFor<Controller>()
    .InstancePerRequest();
```

But I don't know how to a) apply that rule only on Controllers (and\or Actions) with my filterattribute and b) hand over the parameters.

Comment: hey there, did you ever find a solution to this?! i've the exact same problem on a project i'm working on at the moment and search as i might, i just can't find a solution...

Comment: Unfortunately not, sorry

Answer (score 1):

i think i've cracked this. initally i tried the 'WhenControllerHas' route but found that this gets applied to all controller actions... not what i wanted.

my original attribute looked like this:

```
public class MyAttribute : Attribute { }

public class MyFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly MyService _myService;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (_myService.IsSomething())
        {
            return;
        }

        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/my-url/");
    }
}
```

and was wired up in ninject as:

```
kernel.BindFilter<MyFilter>(FilterScope.Action, 0).WhenActionMethodHas<MyAttribute>();
```

after a bit of experimenting, i changed the attribute to this:

```
public class MyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public MyService MyService { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (MyService.IsSomething())
        {
            return;
        }

        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/my-url/");
    }
}
```

and added this to the autofac setup:

```
builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
builder.RegisterType<MyAttribute>().PropertiesAutowired();
```

so far so good! the code now only runs on action results where decorated with the attribute:

```
[MyAttribute]
public ActionResult Index() {}
```

i've still a few things to figure out, namely the order that the attributes are applied (in ninject, it was the order that they were bound up at startup) and how to pass properties down but this feels like it's in the right direction.